# how to save() DB.find({}) all models returned with an method in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want query to DB and edit some value in the returned Query/rows.
when we have a Query/row we can do it with
`model.save()`
but when we have an array of Query,how we can do it?
some thing like this:

```
let arr=await DB_cat.find({parentId:1})
arr[0].name='first'
arr[1].name='sec'
arr.save()
```

Comment: You can use `updateMany` from mongodb collection.

Comment: You can use updateMany if the update is common for all docs and batchWrite if updates are different for all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `for of` like this:

```
  let arr=await DB_cat.find({parentId:1})
  arr[0].name='first'
  arr[1].name='sec'
  for (let item of arr){
    await item.save()
  }
```